# Python3. Видимость переменных. Как увидеть в одной def значение переменной, которая была объявлена в другой def?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, переменные

Графический интерфейс. На каждой кнопке по отдельной функции. В каждой функции используются переменные из других функций.

1. Как правильно объявить эти переменные?
2. И другой вопрос. Как изменять текст на форме в поле `source_le =    QLineEdit('./source/', self)` на путь, который получаем когда
   отработала функция `def get_folder_path_q(self):` ?

***Код***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QLineEdit)

class Muster(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        source_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Quelle\n', self)
        source_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_q)
        source_le = QLineEdit('./source/', self)

        output_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Output\n', self)
        output_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_e)
        output_le = QLineEdit('./output/', self)

        xls_bttn = QPushButton('\nmake XLS\n', self)
        xls_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_xls)

        run_bttn = QPushButton('\nGO\n', self)
        run_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_run)

        qbtn = QPushButton('\nQuit\n', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(source_bttn, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(source_le, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(output_bttn, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(output_le, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(xls_bttn, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(run_bttn, 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(qbtn, 4, 0, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle('OS : ' + os.name)
        self.show()

    def get_folder_path_q(self):
        fnt_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder') + '/'
        return(fnt_directory)

    def get_folder_path_e(self):
        result_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder') + '/'
        return(result_directory)

    def clicked_xls(self):
        filename = result_directory + 'list_fonts.xls'
        list_files = os.listdir(fnt_directory)
        fs = fnt_sizes

    def clicked_run(self):
        bgnd_color = (255, 255, 255)
        txt_color = (0, 0, 0, 255)
        text_xy = str(x) + ' x ' + str(y)
        list_files = os.listdir(fnt_directory)

    fnt_sizes = [14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 36, 48]
    x, y = 256, 256

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    muster = Muster()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***Ошибка***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/fSOf-PyQt5.py", line 62, in clicked_xls
    filename = result_directory + 'list_fonts.xls' NameError: name 'result_directory' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Comment: Вынесите, пожалуйста, второй вопрос в отдельный вопрос на сайте. Он абсолютно не соответствует заголовку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все переменные, к которым необходимо иметь доступ из разных методов класса можно (но не всегда стоит) объявить как свойства класса. Ваш код в таком случае должен выглядеть примерно так:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QLineEdit)

class Muster(QWidget):

    fnt_sizes = [14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 36, 48]
    x, y = 256, 256
    fnt_directory = None
    result_directory = None



    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        source_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Quelle\n', self)
        source_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_q)
        source_le = QLineEdit('./source/', self)

        output_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Output\n', self)
        output_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_e)
        output_le = QLineEdit('./output/', self)

        xls_bttn = QPushButton('\nmake XLS\n', self)
        xls_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_xls)

        run_bttn = QPushButton('\nGO\n', self)
        run_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_run)

        qbtn = QPushButton('\nQuit\n', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(source_bttn, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(source_le, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(output_bttn, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(output_le, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(xls_bttn, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(run_bttn, 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(qbtn, 4, 0, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle('OS : ' + os.name)
        self.show()

    def get_folder_path_q(self):
        self.fnt_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder') + '/'
        return(self.fnt_directory)

    def get_folder_path_e(self):
        self.result_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder') + '/'
        return(self.result_directory)

    def clicked_xls(self):
        filename = self.result_directory + 'list_fonts.xls'
        list_files = os.listdir(self.fnt_directory)
        fs = self.fnt_sizes

    def clicked_run(self):
        bgnd_color = (255, 255, 255)
        txt_color = (0, 0, 0, 255)
        text_xy = str(self.x) + ' x ' + str(self.y)
        list_files = os.listdir(self.fnt_directory)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    muster = Muster()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. `self` указывает на то, что переменная – свойство класса, а значит доступна из всех его методов. Это как раз то, что Вам было нужно.
2. Инициализация всех свойств (в том числе и не заполняемых сразу как `None`) не обязательна, но повышает понятность Вашего кода. Хотя инициализировать заполняемые не сразу свойства лучше не значением `None`, а пустым значением соответствующего типа (например, `''` для строки).
3. Объявления свойств вынесены в начало, опять же, для повышения читаемости кода.

Comment: не могли бы вы объяснить, что такое `свойство класса` и чем оно отличается от понятия `атрибут класса` ?

Comment: @S.Nick Всё просто, это синонимы. Поле, свойство, атрибут. В разной литературе называется по-разному. К примеру, в C# у слова "атрибут" есть другое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Я немного не понял, что происходит, но некоторые вещи подправил для вас. Попробуйте.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, 
                             QFileDialog, QGridLayout, QLineEdit)

class Muster(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('OS : ' + os.name)

        self.fnt_sizes = [14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 36, 48]                   # +
        self.x, self.y = 256, 256                                           # +

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))

        source_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Quelle\n', self)
        source_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_q)
        self.source_le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.source_le.setPlaceholderText("< --- выберите папку для ./source/")

        output_bttn = QPushButton('\nBrowse Output\n', self)
        output_bttn.clicked.connect(self.get_folder_path_e)
        self.output_le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.output_le.setPlaceholderText("< --- выберите папку для ./output/")        

        xls_bttn = QPushButton('\nmake XLS\n', self)
        xls_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_xls)

        run_bttn = QPushButton('\nGO\n', self)
        run_bttn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_run)

        qbtn = QPushButton('\nQuit\n', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(source_bttn, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.source_le,   1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(output_bttn, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.output_le,   2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(xls_bttn,    3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(run_bttn,    3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(qbtn,        4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(grid)


    def get_folder_path_q(self):
        fnt_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder')   # + '/'
        if fnt_directory:
            self.source_le.setText(fnt_directory)
#        return(fnt_directory)

    def get_folder_path_e(self):
        result_directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Choose folder') # + '/'
        if result_directory:
            self.output_le.setText(result_directory)        
#        return(result_directory)

    def clicked_xls(self):
        if self.source_le.text():
            filename = "{}{}".format(self.output_le.text(), '1.txt')  # 'list_fonts.xls'
#            list_files = os.listdir(fnt_directory)
            list_files = os.listdir(self.source_le.text())
            print("\n list_files", list_files)
            fs = self.fnt_sizes                                  # ? fs


    def clicked_run(self):
        bgnd_color = (255, 255, 255)
        txt_color  = (0, 0, 0, 255)
#        text_xy    = str(self.x) + ' x ' + str(self.y)
        text_xy    = "{} x {}".format(self.x, self.y)            # ? text_xy

        if self.source_le.text():
#            list_files = os.listdir(fnt_directory)              # ? fnt_directory
            list_files = os.listdir(self.source_le.text())
            print("\n list_files", list_files)

#    fnt_sizes = [14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 36, 48]
#    x, y = 256, 256

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    muster = Muster()
    muster.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Идеально.